# How to Find the Variant ID of a Product Variant for the Squarespace Commerce API

Tags: squarespace

While using the Squarespace Commerce APIs in order to adjust inventory of a product variant, the Inventory API requires a variant ID to be sent with the request. How does one go about obtaining the variant ID for a product variant?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to get a variant's ID:

**Option 1**: Make a request using the [Squarespace Inventory API](https://developers.squarespace.com/commerce-apis/retrieving-all-inventory) using the API Key you created as `authorization` header. The response will contain product/variant information, including variant IDs.
 [image]

**Option 2**: Go to the page for the product/item in question in a not-logged-in window. Then, add `?format=json-pretty` to the URL. Then go to `item` >  `structuredContent` > `variants`. Find the variant number in the `variants` array by comparing `sku` or `attributes` properties. Once you've found it, grab that item's `id` value. That is the variant ID.
 [image]

**Option 3**: While logged in and editing your site, edit the product in question, go to "Pricing & Variants" and use your browser's developer tools to select the specific variant's image. That `div` will have an `id` attribute of the variant's ID.
 [image]

Note that there are likely other places within the front-end and back-end code that the variantID shows up and can be obtained using dev. tools, such as in the variant drop-down on the details page for a product.